# How to validate Solr cursorMark param

Tags: solr, solrj

I would like to know if there is any standard way to validate `solr` `cursorMark` param.

I'm asking this because my `solrj` client sometimes gets error messages below.

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException | Error from server at http://solr-node/solr/content: Unable to parse 'cursorMark' after totem: value must either be '*' or the 'nextCursorMark' returned by a previous search .
```

Comment: Does this happen at the end of a search result that might have changed? i.e. are there no documents left? Have you tried logging the actual cursorMark that you're using to see if there's something afoot? (i.e. an empty cursorMark, etc.)

Comment: I just want to check the cursorMark before sending the query to solr.

Comment: Yes, but we need to understand _why_ it's saying that the cursorMark is invalid. If it _was_ valid, but the underlying index changed before the next result, making it invalid, you will not be able to detect that on the client side. Instead, you'll need to handle Solr saying that it's invalid and conclude that you've already shown all the results. But first; start by finding out _what_ cursorMark you're sending when the error occurs; that way you can find out if the problem is in your code, or whether there's some other assumption that is wrong.

Comment: I just wanna conduct a basic checking on the cursorMark.
For example, when cursorMark=@, the client program can catch this string and not send to Solr.

Comment: You can see how the cursorMark is unserialized by going to the point where the exception is thrown in Solr's source: https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/6e61811b0e9c5732c31807a138264ff474fa2628/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/CursorMark.java#L187 There's a _very_ general Exception handler there, so there can be many causes for a cursorMark to be invalid; in general it seems like you're going to have to try to unserialize the value yourself to actually validate it, but then it's better to just let Solr do it correctly for you.

Comment: The first naive test would probably be to check that it's at least a certain length (with an exception for `*`), and then let Solr handle the rest of it - but then a new question arises; why not just let Solr handle everything and have validation in multiple places (which will also continue to work if Solr's format changes).